# how to hide shipping Method Block from Cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am Creating New Shipping Method In magento and follow below tutorial.
http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

But it display Shipping method on Checkout/cart page also.

I want to display my custom shipping method only on Onepage Checkout.

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4.

Anybody Can tell me how can i do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to hide shipping Method Block from Cart page you can edit checkout.xml layout file, you can find that file in **frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/checkout.xml**, then look for the

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
```

tag and remove or comment the following line within reference name content

```
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
```

2) You can hide specific shipping method on magento cart by editing cart's shipping.phtml. It's located in **frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml**

Find the following lines:

```
<?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): ?>
<form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>" class="co-shipping-method-form">
    <dl class="sp-methods">
        <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
```

and add some code after the second foreach to skip shipping method you want

```
<?php if ($code == 'your_shipping_method_code') continue; ?>
```

p.s. If files located in base package default theme, make sure to copy that file to your package theme first.

Comment: Thanks for Posting such a good Solutions. I tested both of your solutions. Works Really very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide the shipping method from cart page by using the style sheet.